Clear cookies and cache 2nd iteration in JMeter- selenium script
I have developed a script with jmeter- selenium webdriver. When we launch url it is prompting cookies popup in 1st iteration where as 2nd iteration cookies popup not promoting.
Please help me to clear cookies and cache to get prompt in 2nd iteration

The easiest is just ticking "Create a new Browser at the start of each iteration" box in the relevant Config element:

here is an example for Chrome Driver Config
If you prefer programmatic way (assumes Groovy language):

Remove cookies
WDS.browser.manage().deleteAllCookies()


Remove cache (and in general clear browser history)
WDS.browser.get("chrome://settings/clearBrowserData");
def clearData = WDS.browser.executeScript("return document.querySelector(\"body > settings-ui\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"#main\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"settings-basic-page\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"#basicPage > settings-section:nth-child(8) > settings-privacy-page\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"settings-clear-browsing-data-dialog\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"#clearBrowsingDataConfirm\")");
WDS.browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", clearData);    



